# How to enable word wrapping when I don't know the parent element's width

Tags: html, css

I have an image positioned inside a div, and a description of the image.

```
<div>
  <img src="pic.jpg">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dorus blablabla foo bar woo yay hoopla doo</span>
</div>
```

If the description is long enough, it will stretch the div to be wider than the image. How could I make the description wrap in this case? Specifying an exact width for the div works, but unfortunately the images are of varying size and I can't know the width in advance.

Comment: attach an id to your img tag, and use neat javascript to fetch the image width/height.

Comment: that would work, but I was hoping to solve this without using javascript.

Comment: if you want dynamicly change wrapping attribute, you must use javascript.

Comment: Well, compatibility with users who have javascript disabled is one. And in general I prefer pure css/html solutions whenever possible because I want to avoid things like browser redraws/repaints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>>
  <caption align=bottom>Lorem ipsum dorus blablabla
    foo bar woo yay hoopla doo</caption>
  <tr><td><img src="pic.jpg">
</table>
```

The caption text will be horizontally centered by default but can be left-aligned using CSS. For other approaches, and for explanations why this works best, see http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/captions.html

Comment: This is the solution I ended up going with. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is it a problem that span is positioned absolute? http://jsfiddle.net/d2GQa/

Markup:

```
<div>
    <img src="picture.gif" alt="picture"/>
    <hr />
    <span class="cl-left">Text text text text text text text text text...</span>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

span { 
  display: inline-block; 
  position: absolute; 
  width: 100%;
}

hr {
  clear: both;
  border: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work. Nice! The only downside is that inline-block doesn't work with all browsers. But they should update anyway in that case :)

Comment: Safari >= 2, Opera >= 9, IE >= 8, Firefox > 3. But you can imitate an inline-block in IE < 8: display: inline; zoom: 1;

Comment: Also I realized the description's size is not reflected in the height of the enclosing div. I guess that's what you meant by the problem. This makes stacking the elements a pain, because the elements under "eat" the upper one's description. Oh well, I can just provide some leeway for the height of the div and leave it at that.

Comment: div doesn't enclose the span since span is positioned absolute. Let's find another solution of your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function() {

if(your_condition)
{
    // Enable word-wrapping
    $("span").wordWrap('on');
}else
{
    // Disable word-wrapping
    $("span").wordWrap('off');
}
});

<div>
    <img src="pic.jpg"> 
    <span>Lorem ipsum dorus blablabla foo bar woo yay hoopla doo</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution **without** javascript at short notice. If you are wondering about the floats: It's all about shrink-to-fit.  http://jsfiddle.net/3Qucb/1/